# Same Kind Entities Groups

Tags: python, google-app-engine, data-structures, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Let's take an example on which I run a blog that automatically updates its posts.

I would like to keep an entity of class(=model) BlogPost in two different "groups", one called "FutureBlogPosts" and one called "PastBlogPosts".

This is a reasonable division that will allow me to work with my blog posts efficiently (query them separately etc.).

**Basically the problem is the "kind" of my model will always be "BlogPost". So how can I separate it into two different groups?**

Here are the options I found so far:

> - Duplicating the same model class code twice (once FutureBlogPost class and once PastBlogPost class (so their kinds will be different)) -- seems quite ridiculous.
> - Putting them under different anchestors (FutureBlogPost, "SomeConstantValue", BlogPost, #id) but this method also has its implications (1 write per second?) and also the whole ancestor-child relationship doesn't seem fit here. (and why do I have to use "SomeConstantValue" if I choose that option?)
> - Using different namespaces -- seems too radical for such a simple separation

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: why are you separating them? I don't understand.. if the problem is you want separate model in database, you can use polymodel

Comment: Its not separating the model itself, its just putting a certain model into two different groups... One group is the group of past blog posts and the other is future blog posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well seems like I finally found the relevant article.

As I understand it, pulling all entities by a specific kind and pulling them by a specific property would make no difference, both will require the same type of work on the background. 
(However, querying by a specific full-key, is still faster)

So basically adding a property named "Type" or any other property you want to use to split your specific entities into groups is just as useful as giving it a certain kind.

Read more here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/storage_breakdown

As you see, both EntitiesByKind and EntitiesByProperty are nothing but index tables to the original key.

Finally, an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put a boolean in your "BlogPost" Entity, 0 if it's past, 1 if it's future?  will let you query them separately easily.

Comment: Is this best practice? because it seems rather inefficient. The above example is just an example, what If I wanna separate them into 15 groups, would you save a parameter with "GroupType"?

And when I save a new post I will have to specify its type using a string?

Comment: well doing a parent-child relationship puts you at risk of locking up whole entity groups quickly, and the 1 write/sec limit is not fun to play around....  and while you can use namespaces or duplicate the model class, both ways do seem a bit overkill.  Unfortunately in the datastore a lot of "best practices" are still to be established, since it uses a different way of storing/retrieving.  For what you want done, yeah I do believe a boolean (or int, if you have 15 groups), would be a good way to go around it.

Comment: That's why I asked because I assumed there has to be a better answer :O

Comment: so far, it's really the only one I could figure out when faced with a similar problem, and since I created a specific index for my "kind" parameter, it actually runs quickly and doesn't cost much (one extra index out of 200 isn't that limiting).  If you find a better way let me know, I am interested :P.